# How many quadruples of positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ have property $ab + bc + cd + da = 2016$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> How many ordered quadruples $(a, b, c, d)$ of positive integers have the property
>   that $ab + bc + cd + da = 2016$?

Any hints on a solving strategy or how to approach this problem?

Comment: perhaps this helps:
The given equation can be written as :
$$(a+c)(b+d)=2016=2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$$

Comment: Yes, but after that what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

@Anurag has already observed that $(a+c)(b+d)=2016=2^53^27$. We split the factors into $2^x3^y7^z$ and $2^{5-x}3^{2-y}7^{1-z} $ where $0\leq x \leq 5,0 \leq y \leq 2,0\leq z \leq 1$, The number of solutions in positive (nonzero) integers to $x+y=n$ is $n-1$ so number of solutions to this case $(x,y,z)$ is $(2^x3^y7^z-1)(2^{5-x}3^{2-y}7^{1-z}-1)=2017 - (2^x3^y7^z+2^{5-x}3^{2-y}7^{1-z})$ Now summing over all $(x,y,z)$ we get the total number of solutions to be $\sum_{x=0}^5 \sum_{y=0}^2 \sum_{z=0}^1 2017 - (2^x3^y7^z+2^{5-x}3^{2-y}7^{1-z})=72612 -8 \sum_{x=0}^5 \sum_{y=0}^2 (2^x3^y+2^{5-x}3^{2-y}) = 72612-104\sum_{x=0}^5 2^x + 2^{5-x} = 72612-13104=59508$. Thus there are 59508 such ordered quadruplets.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ the set of quadruples of positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ such that
$$(a + c)(b + d) = 2016.$$
We have
$$
  S = \left\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{N}\,\Big\lvert\, a + c \,\vert\, 2016 \text{ and } b + d = 2016/(a + c) \right\}
    = \bigcup_{d\,\vert\,2016} S_d
$$
where $S_d=\left\{ (a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{N} \,\Big\lvert\, a + c = d \text{ and } b + d = 2016/d \right\}$.

For a given divisor $d$ of $2016$, the solutions of the equation $a + c = d$ are
$$(1,d-1), (2, d-2), \dots, (d-1,1).$$
There are $d-1$ solutions. Also, for each solution of the equation $a + c = d$, the equation $b + d = 2016/d$ has $2016/d - 1$ solutions.
Therefore, we have
$$\vert S_d \vert = (d - 1)(2016/d - 1) = 2017 - d - 2016/d.$$
As the sets $\{S_d\}_{d\,\vert\, 2016}$ are pairwise disjoints,
$$
\begin{align*}
  \vert S \vert 
  &= \sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} \vert S_d \vert \\
  &= \sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} (2017 - d - 2016/d) \\
  &= 2017\times\sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} 1 - \sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} d - \sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} 2016/d.
\end{align*}
$$
Note that $d\mapsto 2016/d$ is a bijective function on the set of divisors of $2016$, so 
$$\sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} d/2016 = \sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} d.$$

The canonical representation of $2016$ is $2^5\times 3^2 \times 7$.
The positive divisors of $2016$ are the integers of the form $2^\alpha \times 3^\beta \times 7^\gamma$ with $0\leqslant \alpha\leqslant 5$, $0\leqslant \beta \leqslant 2$ and $0\leqslant \gamma \leqslant 1$, so
the number of positive divisors of $2016$ is
$$\sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} 1 = 6\times 3\times 2 = 36,$$
and the sum of the positive divisors of $2016$ is
$$
\begin{align}
  \sum_{d\,\vert\,2016} d 
  &= \sum\limits_{\substack{
        0\leqslant\alpha\leqslant 5 \\
        0\leqslant\beta\leqslant 2 \\
        0\leqslant\gamma\leqslant 1}}
        2^\alpha\times 3^\beta\times 7^\gamma \\
  &= \biggl(\sum_{0\leqslant\alpha\leqslant 6} 2^\alpha\biggr)
     \biggl(\sum_{0\leqslant\beta\leqslant 2} 3^\beta\biggr)
     \biggl(\sum_{0\leqslant\gamma\leqslant 1} 7^\gamma\biggr) \\
  &= \frac{2^6-1}{2-1}\times\frac{3^3-1}{3 - 1}\times\frac{7^2-1}{7-1} \\
  &=  6552.
\end{align}
$$
Finally, the equation has
$\lvert S \lvert = 2017\times 36 - 2\times 6552 = 59508$
solutions.